# erb: output repeats if template contains a method definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I expected to see the word "test" appear in the output once and the word "hello" appear once.

But I'm puzzling over the fact that if I do this, **the word "test" is displayed twice**.

```
<div>
  <h3>test</h3>
</div>

<% def helo %>
 <% "hello" %>
<% end %>

<%= helo %>
```

I assume there's a simple explanation for this related to some quirk of erb?

Comment: If you examine the raw html does the word test appear within a div and an h3? Do you have a layout file that may be including the text again? Can you post the raw html output as well

Comment: I can't explain exactly what is happening, but you should not really do this.
You are not in control of which object the helo method is being defined on. Neither are you in control of how <%...%> might be translated into Ruby.
So you are calling an unknown method on an unknown object. It is not suprising that the result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it:

```
require 'erb'

template = %q{
    <div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>

    <% def helo %>
      <% "hello" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= helo %>
}

t = ERB.new(template)
puts t.result

#(erb):6:in `helo': undefined local variable or method `_erbout' for main:Object (NameError) from (erb):10
```

So it seems what you are mentioning is right, but on all hows, you can trick it easily:

```
require 'erb'

template = %q{
    <div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>

    <% def helo
      "hello"
    end %>

    <%= helo %>
}

message = ERB.new(template)
puts message.result
```

And it worked for me.